# chart scale start not 0 and tootltip not shoowing

Tags: charts, ckeditor, tooltip, scale

I use CKeditor4 4.8 and chart 1.02

show corretly in menu and in dialog box, bath:
I inserted for example
value   10   label abc
value   11   label def
value   7    label ghi
in bar y scale start 7 and finish 11
in pie and in doughnut not show legend and tooltip value

have the solutions?

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far?

Comment: <script src="editor/ckeditor.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function Edita(id){CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
     extraPlugins: 'chart,abbr,insertpre',
                                        allowedContent: true,
     enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
     shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV
    } );
}

Comment: I have also this after
 <script src="myJS/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myJS/AnchorPosition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myJS/PopupWindows.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="myJS/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="myJS/CalendarPopup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: and this before 

 <script src="T/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="T/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="T/assets/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
    <script src="T/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="T/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ascript src="myJS/cookiesEU.js" type="text/javascript" /script>

    <script src="T/assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

     <script src="T/assets/js/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>

Comment: @jim jones tanks
<script src="T/assets/js/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>
create a problem NOW is OK